# Ubuntu 21.10 Gnome 40 Citrix Keyboard Combinations

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, wayland, citrix

Since I started using Ubuntu 21.10 with Wayland & Gnome 40 I am having issues with Citrix.

The issue is the keyboard combinations are being intercepted by Ubuntu (Host),  and not passed through to Citrix (Client).

For example, when in a Citrix session, alt+Tab cycles through all the open windows on Ubuntu (Host) not through the Citrix windows (Client).  All the keyboard combinations are behaving the same way, e.g. Ctl+Alt+Del, Print Screen etc are executed on the host instead of the client.

This did not happen in Ubuntu 20.04 & before.

The Citrix Help suggests editing this value:
TransparentKeyPassthrough=Remote.   However, this does not work.
It is not a Citrix issue anyway because I switched over to kfce and all is well.

The only thing I can get to work is remapping the host keys but I do not like that solution.

Does anyone know where to look to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Difficult to understand, so please clarify. Describe the issues you have more specifically and concisely, then you will have more chance that someone can come around with a solution or a workaround.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in Citrix Workspace as well when accessing my work environment. However, your solution is switching back to Xorg and that's actually a workaround. I used this as well but kept on looking for a real solution and I am glad I found it.
In https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/1704870 I read that other applications had this same issue on Wayland and for these there was a solution in Gnome Settings which I couldn't find for Citrix.
Next I came across:
https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2017-March/033526.html
and finally
https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2017-July/034459.html
where this was fixed already in july 2017 by adding two wayland protocols specifically for this.

I then found https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/citrix#Troubleshooting where 2 Gnome settings are given to set those 2 wayland protocols so keyboard shortcuts within a Citrix session work perfectly alright in Wayland.
Besides setting the values through the command line, you could also install the graphical frontend called 'dconf-editor'.

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.wayland xwayland-grab-access-rules "['Wfica']"
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.wayland xwayland-allow-grabs true
```

Don't forget to write Wfica in the setting for xwayland-grab-access-rules with a capital 'W' because otherwise it doesn't work (i.e. for me at least it did not).

So no reason to fall back to Xorg anymore for Citrix as far as keyboard shortcuts are concerned.

Comment: Great this works.  I can't upvote because I don't have enough cred.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me. Should be the answer to this question. Just apply the two 'gsettings' mentioned in the link to archlinux.org in this answer and it works. No restart needed.

Comment: tl;dr run these two commands: `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.wayland xwayland-grab-access-rules "['Wfica']"` and `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.wayland xwayland-allow-grabs true`. After executing these, it worked magically. Didn't even need to restart my citrix workspace connection.

Answer (score 0):

It took 5 months but I solved it.  It is Wayland causing the issue.
In /etc/gdm3/custom.conf uncomment this line:
WaylandEnable=false
to disable Wayland.
Reboot & Citrix will work as expected.